# Erro ao incluir CSS/JS no head de uma página em JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

Estou tentando incluir um CSS em uma view JSF. No entanto, não estou obtendo sucesso.

Abaixo temos um trecho da view:

```xml
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css"  />
</h:head>
```

A versão do JSF é 2.2.12.

Quanto estrutura de pasta, temos:

[image: Onde o css encontra-se]

E o HTML resultante é:

[image: html final]

O que deve estar acontecendo?

Comment: Uma pequena observação, ss assets não devem está na do diretório resources, e sim em webapp.

A mudança de diretorio junto com a resposta de @WellingtonAvelino, funcionou.

Comment: Não tinha notado que você estava usando Maven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode adicionar o CSS ou JavaScript assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Mais sobre [FacesContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html)

**Faces Context**
  usado quando queremos acessar informações relacionadas ao processamento de cada requisição JSF e a renderização da resposta correspondente.

**Nota 1:** A pergunta está voltada para o `JSF 2.2`, mas se aplica as outras versões também.

**Nota 2:** Não tinha percebido que o AP estava usando Maven, se as pastas estiverem no local certo(*pasta webapp*) também é possivel fazer desta maneira:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="index.css" />
```

Answer (score 3):

**RES_NOT_FOUND** está indicando que a pasta **resources** não foi encontrada em webapp, esse diretório apesar do nome, não é o utilizado pelo maven.

O diretório referenciado na questão é **src/main/resources**

O path correto é: **src/main/webapp/resources**

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css"  />
```

O atributo *library* é uma subpasta em webapp/recourses e o atributo *name* é o nome do arquivo em si.